# Java: Selenium Sending Text to Wrong Field

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to set the "Buy It Now" price on EBay advance uploaded.

URL: http://cgi5.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?LikeThisListing&cpg=20&aid=1&from=wn&sid=475543545921&itemid=331639399961&cat1=43537

I'm using:

```
    String BINCSS = "#binPrice";
    String BINXPath = ".//*[@id='binPrice']";
```

I'm trying to set the "Buy It Now" price as "fixed price" instead of "Auction" price. To do this I first click on "Fixed Price" tab and then send price using the previous XPath / CSS.

This works - however it sends it to the wrong field - in other words it sends the price to the "Buy It Now" field in "Auction" not "Fixed Price" tab.

How can I send it to the fixed price "Buy It Now" text box?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The locators address is same in Fixed Price tab and in Auction tab.
So that's why the Buy It price is displayed in both places.

The Relative xpath for Buy It price in both tabs is .//*[@id='binPrice'], So Pls use absolute xpath to navigate to fixed price tab-> Buy It Now price.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, I have found the ""Fixed Price" tab by the link text and performed the click action then pass the value s in the  "Buy It Now".

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='userid']")).sendKeys("enter email");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pass']")).sendKeys("enter password");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sgnBt']")).click();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1650)", "");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Fixed price")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*@id='binPrice']")).sendKeys("500");
```

Hope it will work for you too!!